# What is the distribution of this random variable?

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, percentage

*I have in my possession a theoretical and practical test that evaluates the knowledge of a semester of the subject Probability and Statistics, that is, I am practicing for an exam by attempting questions from an exam from July 30, 2013.*

This test I am doing at home to evaluate myself.

---

### Activity 1

The $ 35 $% of the students who took the first semester of the Computer Technologist, passed the subject MDyL1. It is considered a sample of $ 10 $ students of that semester and the random variable $ X $: number of students who have passed the subject MDyL1, among the selected $ 10 $.

- **a)** Calculate the probability that more than two students in the sample have passed the subject MDyL1.
- **b)** Find the probability that less than half of the students in the sample have passed the subject MDyL1.
- **c)** Determine $ E (X) $ and $ Var (X) $.

---

### Can the random variable $X$ have a binomial distribution?

That is, each student pass a subject independently. It is known that the probability of that happening is $ p = 0.35 $, then the number of repetitions of that experiment should be $ n = 10 $.

That is, $ X $~$B (10,0.35)$, so that:

*-Using the binomial distribution table-*

**a)**

- $P(X>2) = 1-P(X≤2) = 1-0.2616 = 0.7384$

**b)**

- $P(X<5) = P(X≤4) = 0.7515$

**c)**

- $E(X) = np = 10 \times 0.35 = 3.5$
- $Var(X) = np(1-p) = 3.5 \times 0.65 = 2.275$

---

I hope you can help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: 1. Excuse my ignorance -- how does one exonerate (i.e. *absolve from guilt* or sometime *release from duty*) a subject? (academic subjects can neither have guilt nor duty)... 2. You later use the word "exempted" ... are they intended to mean the same thing? Either way, that's also unclear ... what is being exempted from what?  3. Is this a question for some class?

Comment: @Glen_b What I meant was that the student approves the subject, that is, to pass a subject. This is an exam exercise.

Comment: "the student approves the subject" doesn't mean at all the same thing as "the student passes the subject"; the first is about the student's attitude to the subject (perhaps students are filling out a "student evaluation of subject" form), the second is about the student's performance in it (did they achieve a passing grade?), though I guess from your edit you mean the second thing. For exam exercises, please see the [help/on-topic] under *homework* (this may not be homework specifically, the discussion there applies to all routine bookwork questions of this kind)

Comment: I assume by "exam exercise" you mean some form of practice for exams. If this is actually part of your own exam you should clearly state that at the start of your question (as well as follow the guidelines I pointed to)

Comment: What made you conclude that this should be hypergeometric?

Comment: Because it was the only one that occurred to me. But if it is not, then what is actually the distribution of $ X $?

Comment: Wait -- so you're actually doing an exam, not practicing for one? It's important to be clear, but you didn't make it explicit

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry, I thought you assumed you could not be online during a real evaluation. I just edited the question, and try to be as explicit as possible. I hope the context of my question is now well understood.

Comment: No, I didn't assume that; firstly I'm well aware of some students managing to access phones during traditional exams (thought various means) and some courses at some institutions actually have take-home exams (or a take home portion). So I do think it's necessary to be clear. You've edited to indicate it's a practice exam, so that's now quite clear. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: With suitable assumptions it should be hypergeometric but you'd need to know the numbers of successes and failures in the population to calculate it. You can't do that if you don't know $N$. What if $N$ was *large*, like say 1000? How might you quickly approximate that probability calculation? What if $N$ was 2000? How much difference would it make which it was? How small could $N$ be before it started to matter substantially?

Comment: @Glen_b The only thing that occurs to me is that the statement is written in such a way that it is thought to be hypergeometric, but in reality it is another distribution. Or that the teacher is forgotten to measure the total number of students.

Comment: My previous comment contains very substantial hints. You really know of no way to approximate hypergeometric probabilities? The question itself is framed in a way that hints at a different model to consider.

Comment: @Glen_b I really do not understand you. So what is the correct distribution?

Comment: Maybe you need to reread your notes and think about what alternative models you might try. You can't think of *anything* else?

Comment: @Glen_b The distributions that we studied during the course were those of Bernoulli, Binomial, Geometric, Hypergeometric, Poisson, Normal and Normal Normal. I really do not know which distribution fits this. Maybe none? Maybe I have to define a function myself?

Comment: Well, certainly you can eliminate most of these on various grounds. But there will be a reason to reconsider why you might not eliminate them all. Ponder what information you no doubt already have and consider all my big hints about what aspect to look at (specifically in relation to large $N$). For example, did you try it for different N, such as N=1000 and N=2000 like I suggested above, and see how much difference it made (and then ponder *why*)? If not, why not?